# Finding average for a 2d array in python

Tags: python

For one of my coding practices, I need to find the sum and average of an array. I've found a way to get the sum, however I've been struggling to get the code for the average working.
Right now I have my code without the average function:

```
a = [[34,38,50,44,39], 
     [42,36,40,43,44], 
     [24,31,46,40,45], 
     [43,47,35,31,26],
     [37,28,20,36,50]]
     

def sumALL(x):
    sum = 0
    for r in range(len(x)):
        for c in range(len(x[0])):
            sum = sum + a[r][c]

    return sum


print("Sum of all the values: ", sumALL(a))

print("\n\n" + "The average is:  ")
```

I've found a few things online however they all either deal with numpy, in which the website does not support, or they don't work with the code I've made. I'd like to have the average as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a separate function for average

```
def avg(lst):
     lst_el_avg = []
     for i in range(len(lst)):
             lst_el_avg.append(sum(lst[i])/len(lst))
     return sum(lst_el_avg)/len(lst)
```

Then reference it in your code as follows

```
print("\n\n" + "The average is:  " + avg(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `sum()`:

```
sum(a,[])
```

And to average:

```
sum(a,[])/sum(len(r) for r in a)
```

Comment: Pretty sure `sum(a,[])` just flattens the list making the second snippet a TypeError.

Comment: I would however I have to put the sum and average into a print, ("the sum is"/"the average is")  and it's supposed to work with other arrays aswell. I might be doing it the wrong way, however the define function has been the only one that works with what I'm going for so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is to flatten the 2d list to 1d list. You can use `itertools.chain()` to achieve that. Then, you can use `sum()` and `len()` to find the average of the elements.

```
import itertools

a = [[34,38,50,44,39], 
     [42,36,40,43,44], 
     [24,31,46,40,45], 
     [43,47,35,31,26],
     [37,28,20,36,50]]

flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*a))
avg = sum(flat_list) / len(flat_list)

print(avg)
```

#### Output

---

```
37.96
```